# Date transformation for KNN

Tags: machine-learning, data, distance, k-nn

I have data set with date features like `01/01/2019` and I would like to use KNN. However, I cannot find a good transformation for dates that has a meaningful distance result for the last feature.

For example:

f1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 01/01/2019

f2 | 10 | 3 | 12 | 1 | 14/01/2019

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to find the difference in days between that date and another date. You can use the current date, epoch time, or a fixed date. The number of days could be used as a feature in the k-nearest neighbors algorithm (k-NN).

Something like:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

date_string = "01/01/2019"
delta = date.today() - datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
delta_in_days = delta.days
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the time difference in an appropriate granularity(/ies):

```
daysDiffFeature = diffInDays(dateCol)
hoursDiffFeature = diffInHours(dateCol)
```

Then you can use whatever distance based metrics/calculations are required in your algorithsm

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the difference in number of days between each available date and the current day. The larger the number, the older the date will be.